# force SpriteBatch to switch texture

Tags: libgdx

I've a problem which I think is because of a missing texture switch. Here is my render Method in pseudo code

```
spriteBatch.begin();
render stuff
spriteBatch.end();

setup shader with different texture
render some Meshes

spriteBatch.begin();
render stuff
spriteBatch.end();
```

This leads to very strange results. I guess the problem is, that the `SpriteBatch` initially sets a texture, then the shader changes that texture and when the `SpriteBatch` starts the next `batch.begin()` it does not call `switchTexture()` simply because it didn't know that the texture was changed in the mean time.

What could I do to solve this problem? Is there a way to save the current texture, render the meshes and restore the previous Texture? As far as I've seen there is no way to tell the `SpriteBatch` that it should call `switchTexture()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpriteBatch does not automatically switch back to texture unit 0, so you have to manually switch back to it if you happen to have recently switched to some other texture unit to bind multiple textures for a mesh.

Call `Gdx.gl.glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE0);` right before `spriteBatch.begin()` if you've been using something with multi-texturing.

SpriteBatch is not keeping references to any textures outside of a `begin()`/`end()` block, but if you've left the active texture as something other than GL_TEXTURE0, then when SpriteBatch goes to bind the texture for the sprites you're batching, it binds it to the wrong texture unit, so it will draw sprites with whatever is still sitting in GL_TEXTURE0 from one of your recent meshes.